# How to access the property values when DbEntityEntry.Member("JoinTable").CurrentValue return an Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was doing a audit log setup on dbcontext.cs and my next step is to call the primary key values of join table in order log the parent ID in the audit log table.

And now I am working on the calling property of a table called "TAXONOMY" which is a join table of "CONSERVATIONSTATUS" with many to many relationship called "CONSERVATIONSTATUSLINK".

Here is the structure of table generated in edmx:

```
public partial class CONSERVATIONSTATU
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CONSERVATIONSTATU()
        {
            this.TAXONOMies = new HashSet<TAXONOMY>();
        }
    
        public int SPECIESCONSERVATIONID { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TAXONOMY> TAXONOMies { get; set; }
    }

public partial class TAXONOMY
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TAXONOMY()
        {
            this.CONSERVATIONSTATUS = new HashSet<CONSERVATIONSTATU>();
        }

        public int TAXONID { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CONSERVATIONSTATU> CONSERVATIONSTATUS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When it post and go through save changes through dbcontext.cs

```
// This is overridden to prevent someone from calling SaveChanges without specifying the user making the change
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            // Get all Added/Deleted/Modified entities (not Unmodified or Detached)
            foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || p.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted || p.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified))
            {
                // For each changed record, get the audit record entries and add them
                foreach (var x in GetAuditRecordsForChange(ent, userId))
                {
                    this.AUDITLOGs.Add(x);
                }
            }

            // Call the original SaveChanges(), which will save both the changes made and the audit records
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }


        private List<AUDITLOG> GetAuditRecordsForChange(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, string userId)
        {
            var testingvalue = dbEntry.Member("TAXONOMies").CurrentValue;   //Count = 1
            var testingvalue1 = dbEntry.Member("TAXONOMies").CurrentValue.ToString(); //"System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[oraFresh.TAXONOMY]"
            var testingvalue2 = dbEntry.Member("TAXONOMies").CurrentValue.GetType(); //{Name = "HashSet`1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[oraFresh.TAXONOMY, oraFresh, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
        }
```

In the variable testingvalue defined in GetAuditRecordsForChange, when I add watch to it but I can't access the "TAXONID":

```
Name                      Value                      Type
testingvalue              Count = 1                  object{System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<db.TAXONOMY>}
   [0]                    {db.TAXONOMY}              db.TAXONOMY
      TAXONID             300000                     int
   Raw View
      Comparer            {System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer<db.TAXONOMY>}  System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<db.TAXONOMY>{System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer<db.TAXONOMY>}  
      Count               1                          int
```

Could someone provide suggestion do I approach wrong path to call property values or it is possible to access it please? Thanks.

Comment: For those who are searching the answers, I find it out using  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TAXONID"].ToString() on dbcontext.cs which is initiated in from other view page e.g. @{Session["TAXONID"] = Model.TAXONID} and it is much easier to retrieve this primary key values of join table, all the best for coding!